# How to add control input to an op after it was run by a session

Tags: python, tensorflow

Demo code:

```
y = tf.sqrt(42.)
session.run(y)

another_debug_test = tf.Print(y.op.inputs[0], ["debug print:"] + list(y.op.inputs))
add_control_input(y.op, another_debug_test.op)
y.op._add_control_input(another_debug_test.op)

session.run(y)
```

This results in this warning:

`W tensorflow/c/c_api.cc:728] Operation ... was changed by adding control input after it was run by a session. This mutation will have no effect, and will trigger an error in the future. Either don't modify nodes after running them or create a new session.`

And the `tf.Print` op is not executed, as the warning says.

If you remove the first `session.run`, it works as expected.

The question is, how to make it work including the first `session.run`?

And also, why does it not work currently? I guess the reason is that the session somehow has cached the existing graph up to that point, and will not automatically redo that when some op of the graph changed afterwards. But if that is the case, can't I just invalidate this cache? How?

Creating a new session can be costly in practice. It means that I would need to copy over all the variables. (Or not? But this is a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707501/create-new-session-which-shares-memory-and-variables-of-an-existing-session).)

(To answer the obligatory question, why I want to do this: 1. For debugging purpose. 2. For just playing around.)

Comment: I'm afraid the error message is quite categorical, that is not supported. It's not that the graph is "cached" (actually, you can add new ops to the graph with an active session just fine), the graph object is "compiled" to a runtime execution model (e.g. simplifying constants, etc), and the session works with that model. Changes to existing nodes in the graph would require a recreation of the runtime model, and hence the whole session. Probably the only alternative is to save the state of the session (e.g. checkpoint or just extract variable values) and restore it in a new session later.

Comment: @jdehesa Why can't I just recreate the runtime model, but without recreating the session (such that I can keep the variable allocations, etc)? (That's what I mean by "invalidate this cache".)

Comment: I don't really know many details about it, I suppose it should be possible, and that applies to modifying the graph in general too (e.g. rewiring), but it's probably more than just recreating the model (which is rather expensive on its own). It may affect the scheduling of the ops and placement of variables, for example, so effectively you may need to flush the session and recreate it in the process anyway. TF is supposed to be used with a static graph, and that is what the core API exposes. Using it differently is expensive, you can do that but not as part of the normal usage of the library.

Comment: May I ask, why do you want to do this? Maybe there is some equivalent workaround. For example, you could have the control dependency from the beginning, but make it a `tf.cond` operation controlled by a variable or placeholder (with default?), so you get a `tf.no_op` at the beginning and the actual op later.

Comment: @jdehesa It does not matter for me if it is expensive. I want to have this option for any possible operation in the graph (e.g. for some where I get a `tf.errors.OpError`, as said, for debugging purpose). So adding `tf.cond` in advance for every single operation is not an option.

Comment: Note to myself: There is `tf.Session.reset()`. Maybe that works? (Without checking...)