# Create new session which shares memory and variables of an existing session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I already have a TensorFlow session initialized, with a couple of variables in it.

I want to create a new session as cheaply as possible, and reuse the existing variables (such that I don't need to allocate new memory, and I don't need to initialize the variables again), and maybe also reuse the same memory allocator.

Is that possible? How?

(To answer the obligatory question, why I want to do this: Because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707445/how-to-add-control-input-to-an-op-after-it-was-run-by-a-session). Also because I just want to know.)

Comment: You may want to make this question more independent as a standalone question. I had no idea it was talking about tensorflow sessions until i saw the tag and the linked question.

Comment: Not an expert on this, but have you considered using [pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle)?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: I also prefer to add "TensorFlow" to the title, but people here on StackOverflow keep to remove that, and insist that the tag is enough.

Comment: Why using new session? Cant you use the same session and just add operations to the already exist graph?

Comment: @AlmogDavid Not really, but anyway, that would not be related to this question.

Comment: Note to myself: Instead of creating a new session, maybe `tf.Session.reset()` works? (Without checking... Maybe that's not relevant here.)